# How do I extract numbers from list of strings

Tags: string, list, numbers, strsplit, listof

I have a Python list:

```
List1 = ["mohit23", "jimmy24"]
```

I want output as:

```
[23, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using `re.search` along with a list comprehension:

```py
List1 = ["mohit23", "jimmy24"]
nums = [int(re.search(r'\d+$', x).group()) for x in List1]
print(nums)  # [23, 24]
```